# Martingale to compute expected value

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expectation, martingales

Consider a process with an initial state $(A_0, B_0)$ and at each step $t+1$, considering $(A_t, B_t)$:

- $(A_{t+1}, B_{t+1}) = (A_t + 1, B_t)$, with probability $A_t/(A_t + B_t)$
- $(A_{t+1}, B_{t+1}) = (A_t, B_t + 1)$, otherwise (with probability $B_t/(A_t + B_t)$)

Using a martingale, what is the expected value of $A_t$ after $t$ steps as a function of $A_0$, $B_0$, and $t$?

---

Is it a good approach to envision a martingale to which we could apply the optional stopping theorem?

EDIT: We can write a recursion as (given that $A_t + B_t = A_0 + B_0 + t$):

$$E[A_{t+1}\mid A_t] = A_t\left(1 + \frac{1}{A_0 + B_0 + t}\right)$$

Which can be solved to yield (considering $E[A_0] = A_0$):

$$E[A_t] = A_0\left(1 + t\frac{X_0}{A_0 + B_0}\right)$$

The question is what function $f$: $Z_t = f(A_t)$ can be such that $Z_t$ is a martingale with respect to $A_t$?

Comment: Since $|A_t|\leqslant A_t+1$ and $|B_t|\leqslant B_t+1$, $A_t$ and $B_t$ are integrable, and
$$
\mathbb E[(A_{t+1},B_{t+1})\mid (A_t,B_t)] = \left(1+\frac1{A_t+B_t}\right)(A_t,B_t) \geqslant (A_t,B_t).
$$
Hence $\{(A_t,B_t)\}$ is a submartingale.

Comment: Right, but how would you go about calculating $A_t$ given $A_0$, $B_0$ and $t$ from the defined submartingale $\{(A_t, B_t)\}$?

Comment: @onaheimi3 I think your approach is reasonable. Typically a submartingale is not terribly useful for computing such things, because it only gives a one-sided bound; you're looking for a genuine martingale.

Comment: @AaronMontgomery my current problem is finding the correct martingale, because the stopping condition would have to be after $t$ iterations

Comment: @onaheimi3 Yes, that's certainly the hard part -- in general, I'd say that finding a clever martingale which trivializes the problem is the hard part of using the OST to say something interesting. I spent about 2 minutes trying to come up with the right martingale for this problem, and I couldn't immediately see it.

Comment: @AaronMontgomery I know that $X_{t+1} = X_t\left(1 + \frac{1}{X_0 + Y_0 + t}\right)$, but what kind of martingale $Z_t$ could be written with this?

Comment: @onaheimi3 That equation you've written can't be true; it implies that $X_{t+1}$ is a deterministic function of $X_t, X_0, Y_0,$ and $t$. But if we know (for instance) that $X_5 = 3$, we cannot deterministically compute $X_6$, because $X_6$ could be either 3 or 4 with various probabilities. Do you perhaps mean a version of that equation that has expected values?

Comment: @AaronMontgomery Yes, that is what I meant; I am not able to edit it now. I meant actually $E[A_{t+1} \mid A_t] = A_t\left(1 + \frac{1}{A_0 + B_0 + t}\right)$.

Comment: @onaheimi3 It is not immediately clear to me how to leverage that equation to obtain a martingale. (It's possible that it can be done, but it is not obvious to me how.) I *think* that this equation does confirm, however, that the martingale will not be a linear function of $A_t$ (presuming I haven't made errors in my scratch work). Sorry that I can't be of more help.

Comment: Obviously, $$M_t=\frac{A_t}{A_t+B_t}=\frac{A_t}{A_0+B_0+t}$$ is your martingale.